# Font problem with Openbox session

Tags: fonts, openbox, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 13.04 and thought to try out the Openbox session instead of the Lubuntu session which I normally use and have customized to my needs.

One problem I would like help with is the appearance of fonts. The image shows the difference of a window in the Openbox session (top) and the same window in the Lubuntu session (bottom).

[image: Openbox versus Lubuntu]

How do I make the fonts in the Openbox session look like those in the Lubuntu session?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

I created `~/.Xresources` with the following:

```
! Render setting for cairo -> pango -> gtk
Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
```

I then ran `xrdb -load ~/.Xresources` to make the changes to `~/.Xresources` take effect. I got this advice from [Better Font Rendering](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Better_Font_Rendering).